# Is there a fast way to insert values back into a Numpy Array

Tags: numpy

Alright, I have some segmented image data `s` which is defined by a mask `s`, which is basically a 3D binary field where 1 defines a voxel which is part of the segment and 0 defines a voxel which is not part of it. I am trying to get representation of this segment which is as small as possible. this is rather easy, I can use the following:

```
compressed = s.flatten()[m.flatten() == 1]
```

my question is, given `compressed` and `m`, is there a similar Numpy method or an equally fast way to reconstruct `s`?

Answer (score 0):

Alright feeling pretty dumb that I didn't realize that I could've just used the following:

```
a = np.zeros(m.shape)
a[m == 1] = compressed

>>> np.equal(a, s).all()
True
```

Hope this still is of some use to someone who isn't able to figure this out either!